# ping: cannot resolve foo.dev: Unknown host

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

I've got through all of the suggested help option available here on stackoverflow, but none have managed to resolve this issue with valet and the dreaded ping *.dev (macOS only)

Well it appears that the video tutorial needs updating. After a couple of days (time I'll not get back or hair I've pulled out), I decided to go to the larvel install site and see what I was doing wrong, first hand.

It was plain and simple. Valet have change their .dev suffix to **.test**

so after installing and starting valet...

```
 $  ping foo.test
```

The above will return the ping you are looking for.

However, the site still doesn't appear when I use the URL project.test. this just sends me to my apache "It Work's" page. I'm still having to use localhost:8000 to get to view Laravel project and it will causing an issue when I have a number or projects running

Comment: Yeah don't use the `.dev` tld anymore, it belongs to Google. https://webdevstudios.com/2017/12/12/google-chrome-63/. Your problem however sounds DNS related. Are you using dnsmasq?

Comment: Yep, dnsmasq installed and 127.0.0.1 set to top of network.pref lists. Also added etc/resolver/test with nameserver 127.0.0.1, but still only showing "It works!" when I browse to project.test

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - I wanted any URL of the type XXX.foo to resolve to 127.0.0.1 without using a `hosts` file. After installing DNSmasq (using these instructions) all of my *.foo URL requests resulted in `Unknown Host`.

To solve this, I had to add a local DNS entry in my Network Adapters as outlined here: https://gist.github.com/ogrrd/5831371

[image]